# Command run on bash but not from nginx conf exec

Tags: nginx, docker, npm, rtmp, http-live-streaming

So I just build a media server using **NGINX** and **NGINX-RTMP** by [arut](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module), using this [docker image here](https://github.com/brocaar/nginx-rtmp-dockerfile). The server works great, I can stream RTMP and view in HLS.

What I want to do now is taking a screenshot periodically, found [this npm module](https://github.com/tjenkinson/hls-live-thumbnails) that can do the thumbnail generation.

The strange things is, when I tried execute it from the nginx.conf, it won't work. I tried running the command manually from the docker bash and it runs smoothly.

This is my **nginx.conf**, you can download it [here](http://pastebin.com/SH3avkHn)
[image]

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile? Specifically how you are installing the command from npm but the whole file would be best.

Answer (score 1):

Forgot to add `env PATH` inside the nginx.conf file. So that doesn't recognize the command.